# php __autoload function capabilities

Tags: php, oop

I am using the following code to load my object classes;

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once ( 'classes/'.$class_name.'.class.php');
}
```

If would like it so that if it can't find the file, it goes to the Database, finds the table of the data item i'm trying to access. And creates a standard object on the stop which contains the variables which represent the columns in the DB. Is this possible? I know how to check if the file exists with PHP, but I'm not quite sure how I would return the new standard object once initiated with the correct variable names.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Paypal integration?

Comment: Sorry, title was autosaved by stak for previous question i was going to ask another day.

Comment: Just asking, are you really sure, you want to do this?

Comment: Just thaught it would save me a certain amout of time not having to define each class..., but if a class was defined, the system would use that..

Comment: But how should that class know which record to fetch? It could fetch a whole table by classname, but would that be practical? I mean your idea is nice somehow. An auto-loading active record table pattern maybe.

Comment: All I want it to do is return in instance of the class, emtpy. So for example if I had a table "books" with following coloumns; name, isbn, price. I want the autoload to check for a class file and if it doesn't find one, return an empty stand object with the vars; name, isbn and price, but all empty.

Comment: Even more mysterious. What do you want with an object with empty properties?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns all column names for a table as an array (no database specs given, maybe [MySQL?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,158277,158277)). Then initialize an object with empty values (`NULL`) for each of those:

```
$names = get_table_column_names($table);
$values = array_fill(0, count($names), NULL);
$obj = (object) array_combine($name, $values);
```

`$obj` is a standard PHP object containing those columns.

However, this won't work with autoload, as you need to create the class definition on the fly to reflect the type. I would say, you need to inject it via `eval`/`include` with public properties initialized to NULL by default.